# Regex expression to match every nth occurence of a pattern

Tags: r, regex, string, split

Consider this string,

```r
str = "abc-de-fghi-j-k-lm-n-o-p-qrst-u-vw-x-yz"
```

I'd like to separate the string at every nth occurrence of a pattern, here `-`:

```r
f(str, n = 2)
[1] "abc-de" "fghi-j" "k-lm" "n-o"...

f(str, n = 3)
[1] "abc-de-fghi" "j-k-lm" "n-o-p" "qrst-u-vw"...
```

I know I could do it like this:

```r
spl <- str_split(str, "-", )[[1]]
unname(sapply(split(spl, ceiling(seq(spl) / 2)), paste, collapse = "-"))
[1] "abc-de" "fghi-j" "k-lm"   "n-o"    "p-qrst" "u-vw"   "x-yz"
```

But I'm looking for a shorter and cleaner solution

What are the possibilities?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What about the following (where 'n-1' is a placeholder for a number):

```
(?:[^-]*(?:-[^-]*){n-1})\K-
```

See an online [demo](https://regex101.com/r/evANYa/1)

---

- `(?:` - Open 1st non-capture group;

  - `[^-]*` - Match 0+ characters other hyphen;
  - `(?:` - Open a nested 2nd non-capture group;

    - `-[^-]*` - Match an hyphen and 0+ characters other than hyphen;
    - `){n}` - Close nested non-capture group and match n-times;
  - `)` - Close 1st non-capture group;
- `\K-` - Forget what we just matched and match the trailing hyphen.

Note: The use of `\K` means we must use PCRE (`perl=TRUE`)

---

To create the 'n-1' we can use [`sprintf()`](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/base/versions/3.6.2/topics/sprintf) functionality to use a variable:

```
str <- "abc-de-fghi-j-k-lm-n-o-p-qrst-u-vw-x-yz"
for (n in 1:10) {
  print(strsplit(str, sprintf("(?:[^-]*(?:-[^-]*){%s})\\K-", n-1), perl=TRUE)[[1]])
}
```

Prints:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You could use `str_extract_all` with the pattern `\w+(?:-\w+){0,2}`, for instance to find terms with 3 words and 2 hyphens:

```r
str <- "abc-de-fghi-j-k-lm-n-o-p-qrst-u-vw-x-yz"
n <- 2
regex <- paste0("\\w+(?:-\\w+){0,", n, "}")
str_extract_all(str, regex)[[1]]

[1] "abc-de-fghi" "j-k-lm"      "n-o-p"       "qrst-u-vw"   "x-yz"

n <- 3
regex <- paste0("\\w+(?:-\\w+){0,", n, "}")
str_extract_all(str, regex)[[1]]

[1] "abc-de-fghi-j" "k-lm-n-o"      "p-qrst-u-vw"   "x-yz"
```

Answer (score 1):

**1) gsubfn** `gsubfn` in the package of the same name is like `gsub` except that the replacement can be a function, list or proto object.  In the case of a proto object one can supply a `fun` method which has a built in `count` variable that can be used to distinguish the occurrences.  For each match the match is passed to `fun` and replaced with the output of `fun`.

We use the input shown in the Note at the end and also `n` to specify the number of components to use in each element of the result and `sep` to specify a character that does not appear in the input.

`gsubfn` replaces every `n`-th minus with `sep` and the `strsplit` splits on that.

No complex regular expressions are needed.

```
library(gsubfn)

n <- 3
sep <- " "

p <- proto(fun = function(., x) if (count %% n) "-" else sep)
strsplit(gsubfn("-", p, STR), sep)
## [[1]]
## [1] "abc-de-fghi" "j-k-lm"      "n-o-p"       "qrst-u-vw"   "x-yz"       
##
## [[2]]
## [1] "abc-de-fghi" "j-k-lm"      "n-o-p"       "qrst-u-vw"   "x-yz"
```

**2) rollapply** Another approach is to split on every - and the paste it together again using `rollapply` giving the same result as in (1).

```
library(zoo)

roll <- function(x) rollapply(x, n, by = n, paste, collapse = "-",
  partial = TRUE, align = "left")
lapply(strsplit(STR, "-"), roll)
```

### Note

```
# input
STR = "abc-de-fghi-j-k-lm-n-o-p-qrst-u-vw-x-yz"
STR <- c(STR, STR)
```

Answer (score 0):

another approach: First split on every split-pattern found, then paste/collapse into groups of n-length, using the split-pattern-variable as collapse character.

```
str <- "abc-de-fghi-j-k-lm-n-o-p-qrst-u-vw-x-yz"
n <- 3
pattern <- "-"

ans <- unlist(strsplit(str, pattern))
sapply(split(ans, 
             ceiling(seq_along(ans)/n)), 
       paste0, collapse = pattern)
# "abc-de-fghi"      "j-k-lm"       "n-o-p"   "qrst-u-vw"        "x-yz"
```